# Send email to external server using xampp localhost without any external SMTP

Tags: windows, email, xampp, localhost, newsletter

I want to send emails from my Pc(Localhost) to external servers like gmail,hotmail or yahoomail.

There are option to send email using Gmail/Yahoomail SMTP settings but i do not want to use any SMTP setting because of there daily limits.

And we also do not want to buy any email/newsletter services.
We want to create it Fully Free in our PC(Localhost).

Please tell us how can do it using Xampp and any open-source softwares.

Comment: Most internet service providers provide an SMTP server.  If you are hosted in a data center or in the cloud, ask your provider if there is an SMTP server available.

Comment: @eric-j We want to create a server using our PC. not using other SMTP server.

Comment: You'll need Linux. Want to make a web server? Forget Windows.